# Functional of BM and time is martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

We are confronted with an exercise that asks us to find a function $h(t)$ such that:
$$M_t = [B_t + h(t)] \cdot e^{-B_t - \frac{t}{2}}$$
is a martingale wrt to its natural filtration. After applying Ito's lemma using the function
$$f(t, x) = [x + h(t)] \cdot e^{-x - \frac{t}{2}}$$
we noted that if $h(t) = t$ we obtain a nice result:
$$[B_t + t] \cdot e^{-B_t - \frac{t}{2}} = \int_0^t(1 - B_s - s) \cdot e^{-B_s - \frac{s}{2}} dB_s$$
So our aim is to show that the stochastic integral is a Martingale. To do that, we observed ($\epsilon_t = e^{-B_t - \frac{t}{2}}$):

1. $E\left[ \int_0^t \epsilon_s^2 ds \right] < \infty$
2. $E\left[ \int_0^t s^2 \cdot \epsilon_s^2 ds \right] < \infty$
3. We are then stuck in showing $E\left[ \int_0^t B_s^2 \cdot \epsilon_s^2 ds \right] < \infty$

If we show 3. we get that the stochastic integral is sum of martingales, which will prove $M_t$ to be a martingale under $h(t) = t$. Are we on the right track? Any ideas to show 3.??

Answer (score 2):

To show (3) Exchange expectation and integration using Tonelli's Theorem. All that is left is to denote $s=\sigma^2$ and bound

$$ E[B_s^2 \cdot \epsilon_s^2] \le   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\sigma x)^2 e^{-2\sigma x-\sigma^2} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx  \, \, , 
$$
then integrate the result over $s$.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good track? That integral seems to be not convergent (I may be wrong). Plus: how did you reach that point? Have you used the fact that $B_s \sim N(0,s)$ and then used the density of a normal?

Comment: That integral is certainly convergent. yes, we use the Gaussian dist. of BM